# Get the value of the excess textbox into another box

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have textbox1 and textbox2.

and textbox3 were user input the value of 101.

& i want to print out in textbox2 the excess value of textbox1.

```
 <input type="text" name="textbox1" readonly="readonly" value="">

    <input type="text" name="textbox2" readonly="readonly" value="">

    <input type="text" name="textbox3" value="">
```

if the user type 101 in textbox3
the textbox1 only print 100
the textbox2 will print only the excess value 1

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: you need javascript to do this

Comment: You need to do that in JS. Show us what you have tried. And define excess value? Anything more than 100 is excess?

Comment: You must show your work.  Think of codes as cars -- we are mechanics, not manufacturers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample snipppet to help you:

```js
function checkAndPerformCalculation() {
  var enteredVal = document.getElementById('textbox3').value;
  document.getElementById('textbox1').value = 100;
  document.getElementById('textbox2').value = enteredVal - 100;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" readonly="readonly" value="">

<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" readonly="readonly" value="">

<input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" value="" onKeyup="checkAndPerformCalculation()">
```

Comment: jQuery for this? Really? When there is no mention of jQuery in the OP? At least mention you are using an external library for those who aren't familiar with it.

Comment: Ok, converted it to plain JavaScript (removed JQuery).